# WordPress Next / Prev post link shows only a few posts

Tags: wordpress

I have a website with a custom post type `Beers`. The template contains a previous/next post link:

```
<?php previous_post_link( '%link', 'Previous', true, null, 'beer_cat' ); ?>
```

But the previous/next link only links to  [two posts](https://7deugden.pux.nl/bieren/koor-blond), while there are [more posts](https://7deugden.pux.nl/cat/vast/) within the category.

Any thoughts why this could be? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Have you check the setting for post per page? (at dashboard->settings->reading). Also check if your theme implements any setting at options for post per page.

Comment: If i may add to that, within the theme's `functions.php` or related file the hook `pre_get_posts` can be hooked to alter post count. :)

Comment: Thanks for your replies! No Posts per page settings are changed. There is a pre_get_posts function which sets it to -1. So all posts within the category are shown on the [category page](https://7deugden.pux.nl/cat/vast) . If i remove it or change it the problem with the previous/next on the [single beer](https://7deugden.pux.nl/bieren/koor-blond/) page persists.